# how to replace string fetched from mysql's data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$subcats  = DB::connection($wholesalerdb)->table('template_table')->where('LookUp','Sub'.$subcatg)->get();
                  foreach ($subcats as $subcat)
                  {
                          $string = $subcat->Str;

                         if(strpos($subcat->Str, ' ') > 0)
                         {
                            str_replace();//function
                         }
                        // if(strpos($string, ' ') > 0)
                        //   {
                        //       $space = $string;
                        //       var_dump(preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $space));
                        //   }else {
                        //     $cat_sub[] = $request->input('filterSubCat'.$subcat->Str);
                        //   }
                        if (Input::has('filterSubCat'.$subcat->Str))
                        {
                          $cat_sub[] = $request->input('filterSubCat'.$subcat->Str);
                        }

                    }
```

I want to fecth data dynamically and in table , I got a data called "Data New". When I submit a form , the input request will take the form Data_New , hence how is it possible that before I fetch the input request , I want to covert the data of the table , Data New to Data_New?

Answer (score 0):

For that use php `str_replace` function

```
str_replace("Data New","Data_New",$str);
```

Comment: could you pleas example what type of data come from table?

Comment: `data,
dataone,
datatwo,
data new` , now here i want to replace `data new` with `data_new`

Comment: data new is the name of column?

Comment: what type of data new and where are you fetching it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118300/discussion-between-jijo-nair-and-pirate).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Input::has('filterSubCat'.str_replace(' ','_',$string))){
                          $cat_sub[] = $request->input('filterSubCat'.str_replace(' ','_',$string));
 }
```

this resolved my issue